# gzip archive with multiple files inside

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I need to create a gzip archive with multiple files inside, how can I do this without `ArchiveEntry` available for `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` class?

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) on `gzip`:

> Although its file format also allows for multiple such streams to be
>   concatenated (zipped files are simply decompressed concatenated as if
>   they were originally one file), gzip is normally used to compress just
>   single files.

This is why `GZIPOutputStream` doesn't support `ArchiveEntry`.

Normally, multiple files are archived into one with `tar`, then compressed with `gzip` to produce a `.tar.gz` compressed archive.

You could create a `tar.gz` in this way by using the [`Apache Commons Compress` implementation for `tar`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveOutputStream.html#putArchiveEntry%28org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry%29):

```
file_out = new FileOutputStream (new File ("archive.tar.gz"));
buffer_out = new BufferedOutputStream (file_out);
gzip_out = new GzipCompressorOutputStream (buffer_out);
tar_out = new TarArchiveOutputStream (gzip_out);

// .. and then talk to 'tar_out' to write stuff
```

[Here is a more thorough example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/399853983e97dd5c39d4) that compresses entire directories.

Answer (score 6):

GZip compresses a stream. Typically, when people use GZip with multiple files, they also use tar to munch them together

You can find a java tar libarary here: http://www.trustice.com/java/tar/

Or you could use Zip instead of GZip