# Creation gzip archive using Apache Commons Compress

Tags: java, compression, gzip, archive, apache-commons

I succeed to create `gz` archive with expected content, but how can I set the filename inside the archive?

I mean, if archive `myfile.gz` was created, the file inside it will be named "`myfile`", but I want to name it like source file, for example, "`1.txt`"

Current code:

```
public static void gz() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    GZIPOutputStream out = null;
    String filePaths[] =  {"C:/Temp/1.txt","C:/Temp/2.txt"}; 
    try {
         out = new GZIPOutputStream(
              new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Temp/myfile.gz")));

            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(filePaths[0], "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.read(b);
            out.write(b, 0, b.length);

            out.finish();
            out.close();
    } finally {
         if(out != null) out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GZip compresses a stream. Typically, when people use GZip with multiple files, they also use tar to munch them together.
[gzip archive with multiple files inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653683/gzip-archive-with-multiple-files-inside)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I wanted to know not how to add multiple files in one gzip archive but is it possible to rename stream inside gz archive. Like archive name is: "myarch.gz" but stream inside the archive name like "iTextFile.txt".

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. It is a stream of bytes. There is no name inside.